# How to insert new line using sed and variables

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to extract a last entry with keyword "purchased" and append to a next line after a specific string(replacing the already existing line. As an example

contents of order.log

```
discounted
order56
```

run script

```
disc=$(cat status.log | grep discounted | tail -1)
sed '/discounted/a $disc' order.log
```

if the output of disc is order59 then order.log should look like this

```
discounted
order59
```

bot for some reason my sed command doesn't work

```
sed '/discounted/a $disc' order.log
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here, but in your script there is a problem: variables are not expanded inside single quotes, you need to use double quotes: `sed "/discounted/a $disc" order.log`

Comment: All i am trying to do is append $disc to a file below a specific entry. I relaxed to single quotes with double and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

variable sustitution doesnt take place within single quotes `'` use double quotes intsead `" "`

to replace the line matching `order` following a `discounted` line use,

```
 sed  "/discounted/,2 s/order.*$/$dist/" order.log
```

will produce output as

```
discounted
order59
```

`/discounted/,2` selects `2` lines following the pattern match `/discounted/` and apply the substitution.

`s/order.*$/$dist/` if the line matches the pattern `order.*$` is replaced by content of `$dist`

the entire command is given in double quotes `" "`

Answer (score 0):

First check whether `disc` really contains the string 'order59'.

You want to replace the line followed by 'discounted'. Try :

```
sed  "/discounted/{n;s/.*/$disc/}"  order.log
```

It should work fine. Your command missed two things - 1. Next line matching 2. Double quotes for variable evaluation.

Comment: I get sed: bad option in substitution expression

Comment: Works for me. Are u using GNU sed ?

Comment: Perhaps `disc` contains some other chars too !

Comment: BusyBox v1.8.1, this is a small linux pc

Comment: Yes, disc can contain anything: disc often contains / and :

Comment: Can you post `sed --version` output?  Char `/` will create problem.

Comment: This is not GNU sed version 4.0. It can contain links to product page as well: http:// www.store.com/product22.html

Comment: BusyBox 1.8.1 released on 2007. You better update it. If u have awk, then some workaround solution can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes to do that.

```
disc=$(cat status.log | grep discounted | tail -1)
sed "/discounted/ a $disc" order.log
```